# How to return true if length of list is even in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I want to return true when the length of list is even otherwise return false.

```
listnumber :: [Int] -> Bool 
listnumber [] = 0
listnumber (x:xs) =1 + listnumber xs
```

Comment: Hint: your `listnumber` is currently returning the _length_ of the list, rather than whether it’s odd or even. (And that also means your type signature is wrong: it should be `listnumber :: [Int] -> Int`.) Now you just need to do one more thing to solve your problem: take the length that `listnumber` computes, and figure out whether it’s odd or even.

Comment: yea, I want to see whether it’s odd or even, but I this is the closest I got

Answer (score 2):

As bradrn points out, your current function returns the length of the list. What needs to change is the type of what is returned, as you currently return integers rather than boolean expressions.

```hs
listcounteven :: [a] -> Bool
listcounteven [] = True
listcounteven (_:xs) = not $ listcounteven xs
```

[The dollar sign operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-36-) performs function application for us.
This code says that if the input list is empty, return True. Otherwise, we recurse on the negation of the rest of the list. This results in `not` being prepended to the base case as many times as the length of the list, e.g.

```hs
listcounteven []     = True -- The base case
listcounteven [1]    = not $ listcounteven [] = not $ True = False
listcounteven [1, 2] = not $ listcounteven [2] = not $ not $ listcounteven [] = not $ not $ True = True
--etc.
```

However, if you allow yourself to use Prelude functions...

```hs
listcounteven :: [a] -> Bool
listcounteven = even . length
```

The solution becomes concise. [The dot operator](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:.) performs function composition which we can directly return.

Comment: Perhaps it’s worth explaining how repeated application of `not` gives the desired output?

Comment: @bradrn I attempted to do so with some brief example outputs, not sure if they help or are just more confusing to read.

Comment: main.hs:2:43: error:
    parse error on input `='
    Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
    e.g. 'let x = 5' instead of 'x = 5'

Comment: @kulis what code is giving you that error? Note that the second code block in my answer is not code but an illustration of example inputs and outputs. I am not sure where you are suggesting 'let' is needed.